# Multiple ajax call in same change function not working as expeted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've two select dropdowns. On changing the first one creates a default table based on the response with `getFields()` and this is a requirement.

**1st Dropdown:**

```
$("#selectModel").change(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/',

            success: function (results) {

                $.each(results, function (key, value) {
                    $("<option></option>", {
                        value: value.id,
                        text: value.name,
                        name: value.company.id,
                        id: value.id
                    }).appendTo("#selectRole");
                });
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });

        // REQUEST FOR FIELDS
         getFields(function (results) {
             createTable(results);
         });

        $("#editPermissionTable").attr("disabled", true);
    });
```

It also creates the 2nd select dropdown. This part works as expected.
The problem starts when I change the dynamically created dropdown(#selectRole).

**Expected result:** When I change the selectRole dropdown it should reset the default table and then change row values based on the new response from ajax request.

**Problem:**
When I change the selecRole dropdown it only reset the table but doesn't change rows based on the new response.

**Stange fact**: On chrome debugger, I saw it does apply new HTML after 2nd ajax call but it again changed to default one.

**2nd dropdown:**

```
$("#selectRole").change(function () {

        // REQUEST FOR FIELDS
         getFields(function (results) {
             createTable(results);
         });


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:  "/permissions",

            success: function (results) {

                // CHECK PERMISSION TABLE FOR FIELD ID
                $.each(results.data, function (key, val) {
                    $("#permissionTable tr").each(function () {
                        // IF MATCH FOUND REMOVE PREVIOUS AND ASSIGN NEW VALUE
                        if (this.id == key) {
                            $(this)
                                .find("td")
                                .remove();
                            $(this).append(
                                '<td><div class="form-check text-center"><input disabled class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  name="' +
                                val.remove_perm +
                                '"> </div></td><td> <div class="form-check text-center"> <input disabled class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="' +
                                val.view_perm +
                                '"> </div></td><td> <div class="form-check text-center"> <input disabled class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  name="' +
                                val.create_perm +
                                '"> </div></td><td> <div class="form-check text-center"> <input disabled class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="' +
                                val.update_perm +
                                '"> </div></td>'
                            );
                        } 
                    });
                });
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
    });
```

**getFields()**

```
var createTable = function (tableData) {
        //CLEAR PREVIOUS TABLE
        $("#permissionTable").empty();

        // CREATE TABLE
        $.each(tableData.fields, function (key, value) {
            $("#permissionTable").append(
                '<tr id="' +
                value.id +
                '"> <th class="text-muted">' +
                value.label +
                '</th> <td><div class="form-check text-center"> <input disabled class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  name="' +
                value.remove_perm +
                '"> </div></td><td> <div class="form-check text-center"> <input disabled class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="' +
                value.view_perm +
                '"> </div></td><td> <div class="form-check text-center"> <input disabled class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  name="' +
                value.create_perm +
                '"> </div></td><td> <div class="form-check text-center"> <input disabled class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="' +
                value.update_perm +
                '"> </div></td></tr>'
            );

        });
    };

    //REQUEST FOR FIELDS
    var getFields = function (callback) {
        // PARAM VALUES
        var model_id = $('#selectModel')
            .children(":selected")
            .attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/fields'
            success: callback,
            error: function () {

            }

        });
    };
```

Sorry for the long code description but I couldn't figure what I'm doing wrong. If I apply async: false on `getFields()` it works. 
Please help me to identify the issue.

Comment: could you please add ajax response for each Ajax call in your Question ?

Answer (score 0):

For these sort of dynamic processes in jQuery, I'd recommend binding the event handlers for these controls to the actual document level. It's the same thing you have to do if you're automatically adding rows to a `<table>`, etc.

So I would modify your code slightly:

```
$(document).on("change", "#selectModel", function() {
    // perform your generation work here
});

$(document).on("change", "#selectRole", function() {
    // do your work here
});
```

I'm just offering a suggestion. I don't have a way to test your exact scenario, but thought I'd share some of my previous experiences.

Cheers.